# Xamarin binding for AWS SDK

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

**Summary**

- When binding a JAR/AAR built on top of aws-java-sdk, do you have to **EmbeddedReferenceJar** all the libraries below your JAR, down to and including the aws-java-sdk, when down at that low level the AWS SDK for .NET has the functionality.
- Are there any Xamarin packages (Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android) that give an out-of-the box authentication UI with Sign-In/Sign-Up buttons for AWS user pools, Google+, Facebook authentication providers ?

**Context**

I would like to use SignInUI from `aws-android-sdk-auth-ui` in a Xamarin.Android app, which gives you an out-of-the-box UI for authentication to AWS. I've got the `AWS UserPool` and `AWS IdentityPool` setup already.

Unfortunately, the `AWS SDK for .NET` does not expose the equivalent `aws-android-sdk-auth-ui` a java package built on top of `aws-android-sdk-auth-core` (also unavailable in .NET), which is built on top of `aws-android-sdk-core` and finally `aws-java-sdk`.

I thought about binding a java library. I would create a Xamarin binding project for `aws-android-sdk-auth-ui.aar` downloaded from maven Central. I followed the [Binding an .AAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar) tutorial. It builds, but the generated `aws-android-sdk-auth-ui.dll` file is missing some classes. I opened the dll with `Ildasm.exe` and in the `Com.Amazonaws.Mobile.Auth.UI` namespace I only found `AuthUIConfiguration` and `BuildConfig`, clearly missing the `SignInUI` class.

Is it expected that when you build a binding project for an `.aar` file that references other `.jar`, the build succeeds but silently does not produce wrapper classes for java classes who reference missing jars? I would have guessed building would succeed AND would include a wrapper for all classes, but a failure would occur at runtime in codepaths that require the missing jar.

Alright, so I added `aws-android-sdk-auth-core.jar`, `aws-android-sdk-core.jar` to the bindings project, as **EmbeddedReferencedJar**. That did not help, the generated `dll` is also missing the same classes. The build output pasted below does point in the direction of misssing reference jars. See below.

How far do I need to go though, do I also need to embed all the way down to the 80MB `aws-java-sdk.jar`?

I have the following build output:

```
1>JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/ui/SignInActivity : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity
1>JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/ui/SignInUI$1 : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/core/DefaultSignInResultHandler
1>JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/ui/SignInActivity$SignInProviderResultHandlerImpl : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/core/signin/SignInProviderResultHandler
```

- `android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity` indicates that `com.android.support:appcompat` isn't found. How are those supposed to bind? In Xamarin.Android these classes are in
  `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` Nuget package. But the jar does not know it's running in Xamarin.Android. Does that mean I also need to EmbedReferenceJar all the native Android stuff as well? That's a deep rabbit hole...
- `com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/core/DefaultSignInResultHandler`: that one should not error, I did embed aws-android-sdk-auth-core.jar with **EmbbededRefenceJar**

**Update:**

Someone referred me to [Xamarin.GradleBindings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings). I haven't tested this yet, but thought I'd share in hopes this can be useful to other readers.

Comment: why dont you just use the xamarin binding of amazon aws?

Comment: Because as far as I am aware Xamarin has not published a binding for aws-android-sdk-auth-*. In particular I wasn't able to find bindings for aws-android-sdk-auth-core, aws-android-sdk-auth-ui, aws-android-sdk-auth-google, aws-android-sdk-auth-facebook.

I found a list of Xamarin bindings at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/setup.html, it basically only has the aws core runtime, cognito identity, S3, DynamoDB, Mobile Analytics, SNS.